# Default permission of `/var/www` folder in Ubuntu

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I have just hosted my website on Ubuntu Server. It is working fine, but all files are publicly accessible.

like hitting url

mywebsite.com/uploads/ giving the list of all files.

mywebsite.com/php_code/ is giving the list of whole php codes.

How can I prevent this?

I have read this is something related to file permissions. but I am new to Ubuntu so can't get it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing

Comment: I have tried it. It is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of indexing (and not permissions). This setting can be modified in the `apache.conf` file.

To change, open the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

You will see this;

`<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>`

Remove the `Indexes` from the second line and save the file. This way you are **disabling** directory indexing for the site.

Restart your apache server ( `sudo service apache2 restart` ) and the new settings will be applied.

After that when you somebody tries to access the folders, the page will say like the following (following is an image).

[image: Message when trying to access folder]